# What is the syntax of Apache's configuration files?

Tags: apache-http-server, syntax

I'd like to know what the syntax of Apache's configuration files is. Particularly, quoting. Ive read this section:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#syntax

And thought it left out a lot. Whats the difference between the following?

```
Order Allow,Deny
Order Allow Deny
Order "Allow,Deny"
```

Comment: My bet is that the difference is not reflected in the behavior of Apache. Have you seen evidence to the contrary?

Comment: The issue is that I cant find documentation. If I were writing the above, I would just copy what other people do and use the first one. I havent tested any of the other ones.